# A property of the subgroups lattices

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, lattice-orders, computational-mathematics, gap

Let $G$ be a finite group. Consider all the subgroups $H$ such that its subgroups lattice $\mathcal{L}(H)$ is distributive (i.e. the group $H$ is cyclic, by [Ore's theorem](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/duke-mathematical-journal/volume-4/issue-2/Structures-and-group-theory-II/10.1215/S0012-7094-38-00419-3.short)), and among them, let $\{ H_{i_1} \ \vert \ i_1 \in I_1 \}$ be the set of  subgroups having a maximal order. Now for a fixed $i_1$, consider all the intermediate subgroups $K$ of $(H_{i_1} \subseteq G)$, i.e. $H_{i_1} \subseteq K \subseteq G$, such that the intermediate subgroups lattice $\mathcal{L}(H_{i_1} \subseteq K)$ is distributive, and among them, let $\{ H_{i_1,i_2} \ \vert \ i_2 \in I_2 \}$ be the set of subgroups having a maximal order. We iterate the process, and we obtain several chains of (strictly) increasing subgroups: $$\{e\} \subset H_{i_1} \subset H_{i_1,i_2} \subset H_{i_1,i_2,i_3} \subset \dots  \subset G$$

**Question:** Are all these chains of same length?

*Example:* $G = S_4$  (see the subgroups lattice below)
There are $16$ cyclic subgroups: $3+6$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2$, $4$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/3$ and $3$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/4$. So among them, the maximal order is $4$. Next for a given subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/4$, there are two intermediate subgroups (i.e. $\mathbb{Z}/4 \subseteq K \subseteq S_4$) with $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{Z}/4 \subseteq K)$ distributive:  $K=Dih_4$ or $S_4$, and the one of maximal order is $S_4$.
Conclusion, we get three chains of same length $2$, and  isomorphic to:  $\{e\} \subset \mathbb{Z}/4 \subset S_4$

[image]

Comment: Do we really need the `gap` tag here ? ;-)

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov: in fact, I've checked the first examples by hands but I didn't *yet* check much further with gap.

Comment: Any luck with making some further progress?

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov:  a priori this property could be easily check for $\vert G \vert <  512$, I need to write the good GAP program.

Comment: What does it mean "sequence of subgroups having a maximal order" - could you clarify, please?

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov: yes. Let $S$ be the finite set of subgroups $H$ with $\mathcal{L}(H)$ distributive, and let $O:=max_{H \in S} ord(H)$, finally $S':= \{H \in S \ \vert \ ord(H)=O \}$. The word "sequence'' is abusive... $S'$ is the "set of  subgroups having a maximal order'' among...

Comment: Thanks - that's precisely the word "sequence" that confused me. Perhaps you could edit the question. Another ambiguity is that it is not clear whether the word "cyclic" in "all the subgroups such that its subgroups lattice is distributive (i.e. cyclic)" refers to subgroups or to the lattice.

Comment: Would you be willing to show an example of building one chain for some group, to illustrate better what's going on the next step after $H_{i_1}$ is picked up?

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov: yes, see the edit.